# Adding a delimiter under some condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to add one more delimiter ';' at the beginning of the line if there is only one item. For example,

```
a;b
c
d;e

Output:
a;b
;;c
d;e
```

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: The example has two delimiters. Is the requirement to pad it to a width of 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to give you a hint on how you could proceed with this, checking line by line if there is a delimiter found or not. I'll leave the rest to you :

```
while read line 
do 
    if [ $(grep -c ';' <<< "$line") -eq 0 ] 
    then 
       echo delimiter not found 
    else 
       echo delimiter found 
    fi 
done < your_file
```